# Is Classic ASP a lot like PHP and some questions about MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, asp-classic

I don't mean to be controversial.  Close if you see fit.  But I've got to choose the best way to update my Intranet that's in Classic ASP.  I've looked at umpteen framework, still looking and learning, but undecided.  I know that PHP is still being updated and is a fine language, but I was thinking.  If I wanted a framework couldn't I create and MVC framework with Classic ASP?  I'm sure I probably could but that's not the point.  I thought...I could do this or I could create pages with PHP with no framework and where would I be?  Right back with the same predicament with Classic ASP, only a different language.  This makes me think that PHP could be "dangerous" in my enviornment where everyone may not understand or "believe" in MVC.  PHP would lend itself to the cowboy coding and mixing of layers quite easily.  After all it's pretty easy to fire up notepad and just code without having to worry about layers and layers of "stuff."

My question:  Is this true of all the platforms and languages?  Are there any that are designed in such away that it would be pretty hard to fall back into the evil ways?  The only thing I can see is one, ASP.NET MVC.  It'd be pretty hard to start in that and end up not using it.  Java EE 6.  I don't know.  I know Java has been pretty MVCish from long ago.

Thank you for any thoughts.  I don't need to be lectured on MVC goodness.  That's not my point.  I just had an observation and wanted thoughts on how to keep my project MVC.

Comment: It's more of a social  / co-worker eductation question, but yeah, if you don't really want the possibility of a procedural setup PHP wouldn't be your choice. On the other hand, it would be a more steep learning curve for your coworkers, while PHP (and others) could still be a nice place to be able to go both ways. Most likely, your choice would be a language close to what your coworkers already know, and using an MVC pattern should be an agreed upon convention.

Comment: actually i am a bit of a noob when it comes to MVC and based on first impressions, i cant help noticing that the "view" in MVC looks suspiciously like a classic ASP page with all the <% and %> all over the place. Hark back to good old days! :-)

Comment: Voted to close. It is hard to say what is really being asked here. PHP has MVC frameworks and as long as you keep your developers in line with a standard (via documentation etc) you should not have a problem with stuff being allover the place. As well, this can happen with any language if the developers are not held to a standard. It is more or less human interference that flaws it up, not the language.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record. Nowadays, Classic ASP also have a lot of Frameworks including MVC ones like ASP Xtreme Evolution, Ajaxed, Troika.ASP and a lot more. There are good things in Classic ASP just like in any other language, as there are terrible things written in Java, Ruby, Python and probably in all languages. Before throwing yourself into a new enviroment, I would recommend you to read [ASP a misinterpreted technology](http://zend.lojcomm.com.br/entries/asp-a-misinterpreted-technology/) to notice that Classic ASP has a lot of good parts, including the Javascript ones!